# VS2010, C#:  два вопроса  об dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagrid, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Добрый день!

Разрабатываю приложение по учету клиентских заявок и отгрузки по ним товаров клиентам. использую MSSQL и C#. задачу сам себе придумал, учусь так. Вопросы в следующем.

**1 вопрос**  - есть форма, а на ней `dataGridView`. Выделяем строку левой кнопкой мыши. Правой кнопкой кликаем - появляестя контактстное меню, но строка не выделяется - остается выделенная  левой кнопкой мыши строка. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы кликаем ПКМ dataGridView, и строка выделилась, и контекстное меню появилось?

**2 вопрос**  - `dataGridView` и событие `dt_dataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick`. Т.е. юзер выбирает строку в гриде, два раза кликает ЛКМ по ней (строке) форма закрывается (текст в обработчике : `Close()`;), и выделенной значение передается в родительскую форму. И механизм работает. Но в некоторых случаях, можно 50 раз кликнуть по строке в гриде, она  выделится, но ничего не произойдет. Но кликнуть пару раз на строке выше или ниже - и обработчик сработает! Т.е. получается, что указанное событие не прореагировало на двойное нажатие мыши. Как заставить его работать нормально?

Простите за детcкие вопросы, но очень хочу разобраться.

Comment: Если вы учитесь, бросьте умирающий WinForms и пишите сразу на WPF.

Comment: @VladD, вы слишком категоричны. Некоторые вещи действительно удобнее делать на WinForms.

Comment: @Макс Жуков: Возможно, вы правы. А в чём может быть преимущество? Я и правда не знаю. Мне кажется, например, что за исключением тривиальных случаев простейшего UI отсутствие layout manager'а — фатальный недостаток.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому вопросу смотрите в сторону события [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx).

По второму - сталкивался с подобной проблемой, оптимальным оказался путь создания столбца кнопок, но клику на которых и производились действия. Использовал [DataGridViewButtonColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx).